# What does this mean and how can I get it off my computer?

Tags: macbook-pro

[image]

What does this mean and how can I get it off my computer?

Answer (score 3):

This is called Target Disk mode, it activates when you start your Mac while pressing and holding the T key. Try to shut down your Mac with the power button and turn it on, it should boot properly.

[image: USB and Thunderbolt icons on a black screen]

See this [Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156) for the screens you could potentially see on start up.

Comment: If it won’t go away, you may have a keyboard problem.

Comment: @KateBarclay Welcome to Ask Different! The preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to [your reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)).  Please see the [About] page and also [answer]. - From Review